# Javascript: How to reuse method for creating child instances without creating circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
abstract class Fruit {
    private content: Fruit[] = [];

    addChild() {
        // Pick one at random (using this as an example instead of the actual criteria that determines this)
        const type = pickOne(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']);

        switch (type) {
            case 'apple':
                this.content.push(new Apple());
            case 'banana':
                this.content.push(new Banana());
            case 'cherry':
                this.content.push(new Cherry());
        }
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit { }

class Banana extends Fruit { }

class Cherry extends Fruit { }
```

How can I restructure this without creating circular dependencies so that:

1. Each class is in a separate file
2. The `addChild()` method is available on all children without duplicating the code

I've read that it is generally a bad pattern for the base class to know anything about child classes but I'm not sure what a better pattern would look like.

[Example that might make more sense](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20List%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20children%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loadChildren()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.all(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.children.map(id%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fetchListData(id).then(data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(data.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'ol'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20OrderedList()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'ul'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20UnorderedLIst()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20OrderedList%20extends%20List%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20UnorderedLIst%20extends%20List%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Data%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'ol'%20%7C%20'ul'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fetchListData(id%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3CData%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20type%3A%20'ol'%20%7C%20'ul'%20%3D%20'ol'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(Math.random()%20%3C%200.5)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%20%3D%20'ul'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

**Edit:** Removed `type` as an argument

Comment: I think generally this really depends on a use case. You really should think about what problems you might run into, especially if you want to change anything.

Comment: It seems weird that the children are both a subclass of the Fruit and a part of it's content. Shouldn't your class be a FruitContainer and the fruits don't inherit from it?

Comment: Is there a reason your content Array is split by subclass type instead of just being Array<Fruit>?

Comment: @Axnyff All fruit can have an array of nested fruits (doesn't really make sense with the fruit names, sorry)

Comment: @WilliamOliver yeah that probably makes more sense. I was trying to show that the class `Fruit` isn't used by itself but switching it to an abstract class makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the abstract class from the factory class (create new instances):

```
// fruit.ts
abstract class Fruit {
    private content: Array<Fruit> = [];

    addChild(child: Fruit) {
        this.content.push(child);
    }
}

// fruit-factory.ts
class FruitFactory {
    create(type: 'apple' | 'banana' | 'cherry'): Fruit {
        switch (type) {
            case 'apple':
                return new Apple();
            case 'banana':
                return new Banana();
            case 'cherry':
                return new Cherry();
        }
    }
}

// apple.ts
class Apple extends Fruit { }

// banana.ts
class Banana extends Fruit { }

// cherry.ts
class Cherry extends Fruit { }
```

The [Factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is useful to isolate and reuse the code that creates an object.

In your more detailed example, the `loadChildren` does not have to be tied to the `List` abstract class. This makes the `List` abstract have 3 responsibilities: being a list, loading data from an external source and creating new entities.

A guiding principle for maintainable code is the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) where each class have a single responsibility.

I suggest that you split your `List` object in 3 classes, based on the identified responsibilities: `abstract class List`, `class ListFactory` and `class DataFetcher`.

This will allow you to define a good interface for each of these classes.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably what I'm missing, will do some more reading on this.

Comment: This means that Fruit can't use FruitFactory right? If the `addChild()` method is quite complex and has to determine the correct type then I think it won't work so well. In that case would the solution be to move the `addChild()` method to a separate file that has no dependencies on `Fruit` and then import it into each child fruit class?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without a better example. Here, it makes no sens to me that a fruit have children. Can you explain your use case and I might be able to help you ?

Comment: Sorry, let me to try to think of a better example than fruit. Maybe lists? Each list can have a list inside it. It might be a `ul` or `ol` and then you have a method `fetchChild` which fetches the child list based on the id and creates a `ul` or `ol` based on the response. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I think the solution holds for Lists as well. You define an abstract `AbstractList` which defines an `addChild` and `fetchChild` method and 2 child classes `UlList` and `OlList`. That just extends the `AbstractList`

Comment: I add a link to a new example in my question which might make more sense.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks so much for your help! Also I really appreciate the links to the principles. It is really good to see the reasoning behind stuff as I'm mostly self taught from examples so I think I've missed a lot of that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the constructor instead of a string:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    private content: Fruit[] = [];

    addChild<F extends Fruit>(C: new (...args: any) => F) {
        this.content.push(new C());
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit { }

class Banana extends Fruit { }

class Cherry extends Fruit { }
```